# How to pass data from block in one view controller to another

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, mailcore2

I am trying to create mail client, I have very simple GUI in my app:

- Login button
- Email placeholder
- Password placeholder

I use MailCore2 library to fetch messages and etc.
And in one moment I suppose that it is very good idea to pass data from my ViewController to my TableViewController.
So, I fetch my messages in my first ViewController and pass this array to my second TableViewController, thats how I doing this:

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self makeSession:@"zurgsrushmber@gmail.com" withPassword:@"mypassword"];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Inbox" sender:self];
}
```

And my "makeSession" method:

```
- (void)makeSession:(NSString *)email withPassword:(NSString *)password {
    MCOIMAPSession *session = [[MCOIMAPSession alloc] init];
    [session setHostname:@"imap.gmail.com"];
    [session setPort:993];
    [session setUsername:email];
    [session setPassword:password];
    [session setConnectionType:MCOConnectionTypeTLS];

    MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKind requestKind = MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders;
    NSString *folder = @"INBOX";
    MCOIndexSet *uids = [MCOIndexSet indexSetWithRange:MCORangeMake(1, UINT64_MAX)];

    MCOIMAPFetchMessagesOperation *fetchOperation = [session fetchMessagesOperationWithFolder:folder requestKind:requestKind uids:uids];



    [fetchOperation start:^(NSError * _Nullable error, NSArray * _Nullable fetchMessages, MCOIndexSet * _Nullable vanishedMessages) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error downloading message headers:%@", error);
        } else {
//            NSLog(@"The post man delivereth:%@", fetchMessages);
            self->myTableViewController.messages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchMessages];
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"The post man delivereth:%@", myTableViewController.messages); // Displays "The post man delivereth:(null)"
}
```

As you can see, I am using my inVar from ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MailCore/MailCore.h>
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    __block MyTableViewController *myTableViewController;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailTextField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;


@end
```

And my TableViewController's interface file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    __block NSArray *messages;
}

@property NSArray *messages;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

NSLog shows me "null" if I try to use it outside block, however, my variable self->myTableViewController.messages has data, but only inside block.

**UPDATE:**
I tried something like this, but I get infinite loop...

```
    __block BOOL finished = NO;
    [fetchOperation start:^(NSError * _Nullable error, NSArray * _Nullable fetchMessages, MCOIndexSet * _Nullable vanishedMessages) {

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error downloading message headers:%@", error);
        } else {
            self->myTableViewController.messages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchMessages];
//            NSLog(@"The post man delivereth:%@", self->myTableViewController.messages);
            finished = YES;
        }
    }];
    while (!finished);
    NSLog(@"The post man delivereth:%@", self->myTableViewController.messages);
```

Comment: The code outside the block runs before the fetching operation is executed so of course there is no messages there. But what's wrong with setting messages inside the block?

Comment: What kind of controller does the `@"Inbox"` segue present?

Comment: @PhillipMills, TableViewController

Comment: If you mean `MyTableViewController`, then you're creating 2 different ones...one with the `initWithNibName` and one with the segue.

Comment: No no, I have only one TableViewController - "MyTableViewController", but It's not the main problem, the main problem is that NSLog displays null after fetch, but I guess @AndreyChernukha прав

Comment: @AndreyChernukha, as you can see, I init array inside fetch operation block, isn't it?